# Chromecast remote display VS Nearby Connections API

Tags: android, chromecast, latency, android-tv, google-nearby

I'm working on a mobile game app that receives the moves from an external Bluetooth(BLE) sensor.

I wish to show the game on the TV in low latency, so the users make the moves with the sensors and look on the TV.

Options I've thought on:

1. Chromecast Remote Display.
2. Build Android TV app of the game display only and use Nearby Connections API to send the game screen data from the App to the TV.
3. Build Full Android TV game app that connects to BLE sensor directly.

Which option do you think will work in the lowest latency?

As Nearby Connections API also works on Wifi, does it have better connectivity and more TV models support it, than direct TV<->Bluetooth connection?

also, open to other ideas (-;

Answer (score 0):

Nearby Connections is a great way to go. Just keep in mind that Nearby Connections will decide under the hood the way it will connect devices (can be bluetooth, BLE, wifi hotspots), so no guarantees regarding Wifi. Also, it is Android-only solution.